# localStorage returning null even though it can be logged in console through browser

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I saved an item to localStorage. But it keeps returning null. I can log it out in the console on my browswer by writing localStorage, and the string exists as the key value `product: basic bundle` when I do that. However, when I try to console.log it from within my program, It returns null. The item (`this.product[0].name`) in local storage is a string that says "basic bundle"

I set it using

```js
window.localStorage.setItem("product", this.product[0].name);
```

then get it using

```js
const product = window.localStorage.getItem(product)
```

and tried to log it out by writing

```js
console.log(product);
```

I have a different variable that I set and get the same way from localStorage and on the same pages that I can access and utilize in my code. But for some reason, this one won't work. any suggestions?

Comment: You didn't post any context. Where is the `setItem()` and where is the `getItem()`?

Comment: Set item is on a different page in my site. Once the user sends the information, they are redirected to an external domain, and once the transaction is complete in the external domain, they are redirected to the page where I get the item from localStorage. This is all happening in a Vue application.

Comment: `window.localStorage.getItem(product)` should be `window.localStorage.getItem("product")`, but your code should throw an error like "can't access lexical declaration 'product' before initialization"

Comment: Thanks Kaiido. this works. I wonder why i could get the other item from local storage without the quotation marks... and I did not throw any error. weird.

Comment: @Ren in that case you may have a variable called `product` which is evaulating to a string